# Blender and pyopengl rendering have some differences

Tags: rendering

I'm using Blender to make the groundTruth of a differentiable renderer which rendered with pyopengl.
However, I derived Blender's camera matrix and projection matrix and rendered them with pyopengl, but there are always some small differences. Pyopengl rendering will enlarge my model a little.I don't know what's going on. Does anyone have a standard export process in this regard? What's the difference between blender and pyopengl.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. I don't have any knowlendge of pyopengl, all I can say is that exporting Blender camera to other software usually result in a perfect match. Did you tried to import other software's scenes in pyopengl? Are they shown correctly?

Comment: I am not very familiar with rendering software and can only operate blender. The problem now is that rasterizing with pyopengl will lead to slight deformation of the rendered image, which does not fully correspond to blender. I don't know if it is related to the accuracy of the camera matrix